# Which HTTP header maps to Apache's %u log format token?

Tags: httpd, httpd.conf, http-headers

We have an `httpd.conf` that contains the following log format and uses the `%u` token for logging the remote user:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %D" combined
CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /var/log/httpd/access.log.%Y%m%d 86400" combined
```

Unfortunately, no user identifier ever appears in the access log. The third token in every logged line just contains a hyphen instead of the user, like this:

```
192.168.15.124 - - [20/Apr/2018:12:06:49 +0200] "GET /some/resource" ...
```

Does anyone know how the value of `%u` is set by Apache? Is there a particular HTTP header for which `%u` is replaced? I explicitly set a few headers like `X-Remote-User`, `Remote-User` or just `User`, but I keep just seeing hyphens...

Any clues about how Apache sets the `%u` would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This field corresponds to a username used in `Authorization` HTTP header used for [The 'Basic' HTTP Authentication Scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617).

Comment: I actually see `Authorization` headers, too. We have two levels of Apache proxies, the first one does the authorization and the second one just 'reroutes' traffic to different application servers/backends. On the first proxy, the user IDs are all logged as expected, but on the second one they are not.

Answer (score 0):

Does the Apache instance producing those empty users have a valid users provider, e.g. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_basic.html#authbasicprovider? I figure that, without one, there's no way for Apache to know how to populate that field in the log.